# Reverse Posa's inequality

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, analytic-number-theory

Denote $p_n$ be the $n$th prime number.

> **Theorem(Posa)** For any$k\in\mathbb{N}$,there is a constant $N$ such that each $n>N$,have
> $$p_1p_2\cdots p_n>p_{n+1}^k\quad (*)$$

My question:How can we find the largest nature number $n$,such that
$$p_{n+1}^k>p_1\cdots p_n$$
More then ,is there a exact formula about the least constant $N$ such that $(*)$holds？
I think we must find a more exact bound of $p_n$.

For example：when $k=3$ ，note [Bertrand's postulate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand%27s_postulate) gives

$$p_{n+1} \lt 2p_{n} \lt 4p_{n-1} \lt 8p_{n-2} $$

Thus,

$$p_{n+1}^3 \lt (2p_{n})(4p_{n-1})(8p_{n-2}) = 64(p_{n-2}p_{n-1}p_{n}) $$

For $n = 5$,

$$13^3 = 2179 \lt 2(3)(5)(7)(11) = 2310 $$

so it's true. For $n = 6$,

$$17^3 = 4913 \lt 2(3)(5)(7)(11)(13) = 30030 \tag{5}\label{eq5A}$$

so that is also true. For $n \ge 7$,

$$\prod_{i=1}^{n}p_i \ge (p_1 p_2 p_3 p_4)p_{n-2}p_{n-1}p_{n} = 210(p_{n-2}p_{n-1}p_{n})$$

Since $210 \gt 64$,  is also true for all $n \ge 7$.So for $n\ge 5$，
$$p_1p_2\cdots p_n>p_{n+1}^3$$
and the least constant$N=5$.

Answer (score 1):

Its equivalent to $\ln p_1 p_2 \cdots p_n  > k \ln p_{n+1}$ and so pick $ k < \frac{\theta(p_n)}{\ln p_{n+1}} \approx \frac{p_n}{\ln p_n} $

Comment: ummm.I mean to find the least $n$ such that (*) is true for each fixed $k$.

Comment: Because $\frac{p_n}{\ln p_n } \approx \pi(p_n) = n $ that means that $k<n$ and $\lim \limits_{k \to \infty} \frac{n}{k}=1$ and since $ \pi(x) \sim \frac{n}{\ln n} (1+\frac{1}{\ln n})$ then a better approximation for $n$ will be $n \approx k(1+\frac{1}{\ln k}) $, you can make better approximation using Dusart approximation for $\pi(x)$

Comment: Can the error between the N given by this formula and the actual N be known?